# Write to file in C using variable as file name

Tags: c, file, variables, fopen, fwrite

I am trying to write to a file in C using fopen but the extension of the file I want to write to must be a variable.
The extension is stored in the variable `extension`, while the text I want to write is stored in `result`.
I tried to use this function but no file is created.

```
void createAndWrite(char* result, char* extension){
    char buf[100];
    sprintf(buf,"%s.%s","outputFile",extension);

    FILE *fh = fopen (buf, "wb");
    if (fh != NULL) {
        fwrite (result, sizeof (result), 1, fh);
        fclose (fh);
    }
}
```

If I manually write the name of the file it works perfectly e.g. `FILE *fh = fopen ("outputFile.txt", "wb");`: the file is created and the output is correct.
I also tried using functions like `strcat(), snprintf()` or specifying the whole file path but nothing works.
It's not a problem of accessing to the the extension variable bacause if I do a `printf("%s",buf);` I can see the correct file.
How con I solve it?

Comment: Try at the beginning to fill buf with \0, maybe it has some garbage from memory.

Comment: That `fwrite()` call doesn't look right. `sizeof (result)`?

Comment: If  `result` is a `nul`-terminated character string, then you want `strlen(result)` in place of `sizeof (result)`. (Or, more likely, `strlen(result)+1`!)

Comment: Also needs a [mcve] and better description of what "nothing happens" means.

Comment: `sizeof (result)` will be the size of a `char *` which will probably be 4 or 8 on your system. You probably want `strlen(result)` or use `fputs` instead of `fwrite`.

Comment: The proper alternative of `sizeof(result)` may be `strlen(result)+1` if you want to add the terminating null-character, depending on the file format to create.

Comment: Thank you all, I was referring to the fact that this code does not create any file. It creates the file and write the correct output only if I manually write the name of the file e.g. `FILE *fh = fopen ("outputFile.txt", "wb");`

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof(char* result) will always result in 4 (32 bit target) or 8 (64 bit target)
```

Unless the actual length of `result` matches 3 or 7 bytes (considering also the `NULL` terminator) the wrong length information will cause `fwrite (result, sizeof (result), 1, fh);` to fail.  Replace this with:

```
fwrite (result, strlen(result) + 1, 1, fh);
```

Aside: (not part of the primary problem) Regarding the following:

```
char buf[100];
sprintf(buf,"%s.%s","outputFile",extension);
```

Even though `sprintf()` does append a `\0` termination to the resulting buffer for a successful call, as a rule it is a good habit to initialize.  buffers to be used in string functions.  Eg: :

```
 char buf[100] = {0};//populates entire memory location with `nul` characters.
```